# setting camera rotation changes camera's position

Tags: three.js

when i have the following code:

```
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width/height, 1, 10000 );
    scene.add( camera );
    camera.rotation.set(-0.09388335, 0.9945234, 0.0474389);
    camera.position.z = 100;

    camera.rotation.set(-0.09388335, 0.9945234, 0.0474389);
```

at render time the position of camera.matrixWorldInverse changes. Anyone knows why?

My guess is that because you are rotating the camera's rotation locally you are changing its position globally. If that's the case then why would the rotate around world axis in the following work:

[How to rotate a object on axis world three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119753/how-to-rotate-a-object-on-axis-world-three-js)

Comment: Why are you setting the rotation twice in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at camera.matrixWorldInverse not camera.matrixWorld