# setEulerFromRotationMatrix does not exist in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to use the following to rotate my mesh on its own y axis:

> // Rotate an object around an arbitrary axis in object space var
>   rotObjectMatrix; function rotateAroundObjectAxis(object, axis,
>   radians) {
>       rotObjectMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
>       rotObjectMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);
>       object.matrix.multiplySelf(rotObjectMatrix);      // post-multiply
>
> ```
> // new code for Three.js r50+
> object.rotation.setEulerFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
>
> // old code for Three.js r49 and earlier:
> // object.rotation.getRotationFromMatrix(object.matrix, object.scale); }
> ```

THe problem is I am getting a "Object has no method 'setEulerFromRotationMatrix'". Has this method been deprecated? How do I get around this?

Comment: Are you sure object.rotation is a vector3? did you overwrite it with something else? http://threejs.org/docs/59/#Reference/Math/Vector3

Comment: object is a mesh: new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( meshMaterial));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy now.

```
object.rotateY( radians );
```

There is also

```
object.rotateOnAxis( axis, radians );
```

three.js r.59

Comment: this is not working anymore with the current version

Comment: @JothiKannan Both functions are supported in the current version r.67.

Comment: oh so the problem is only for me?? it is not working to me, am rotating my object that is loaded using OBJMTLLoader, even `object.rotation.x = rotation;` also no working where rotation+1.5; with globally declared as 0

Comment: @JothiKannan Yeah it is not. Use this `mesh.position.setFromMatrixPosition(_this.matrix)` I think it is unified between getPositionFromMatrix and setEulerFromMatrix. It turns out to become a single line.