# Rotate object around world axis

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I am trying to rotate an object around the world axis. I've found this question: [How to rotate a object on axis world three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119753/how-to-rotate-a-object-on-axis-world-three-js)

But it didn't solve the problem by using this function:

```
var rotWorldMatrix;

// Rotate an object around an arbitrary axis in world space       
function rotateAroundWorldAxis(object, axis, radians) {
    rotWorldMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    rotWorldMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);
    rotWorldMatrix.multiplySelf(object.matrix);        // pre-multiply
    object.matrix = rotWorldMatrix;
    object.rotation.getRotationFromMatrix(object.matrix, object.scale);
}
```

`multiplySelf` and `getRotationFromMatrix` are not defined (I'm getting a console error). How to fix the problem?

**Update**

I tried to use `Quaternion`, but it doesn't seem to behave correctly. I'm trying to rotate an object according to the user click, this is the function that I've written:

```
function mouseUp(event) {
    var x= event.clientX;
    var y= event.clientY;
    var dx= (x - xBegin);
    var dy= (y - yBegin);

    var quaternion= new THREE.Quaternion();
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Quaternion(dy,dx,0).normalize(),Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)/250.0);
    object.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(quaternion,object.quaternion);
}
```

It rotates correctly as long as the object is in vertical or horizontal position, but if it's for example at 45 degrees from the x axis, it rotates very slowly and in the opposite direction of the click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the object does not have a rotated parent, you can rotate the object around a world axis like so:

```
object.rotateOnWorldAxis( axis, angle );
```

`axis` must be normalized (have unit length); `angle` is in radians.

three.js r.92

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you see my edit? I tried to use Quaternion to rotate an objects simultaneously around the x and y axis (according to the user gesture), but it doesn't rotate the object correctly.

Comment: Please do not change the question after it has been answered. I answered your original question. Please accept this answer, and if you are having additional problems, please make a new post... I expect you can figure out the problem yourself, anyway -- you are passing in a `Quaternion` where you should be passing in a `Vector3`.