# ThreeJS - rotation around object's own axis

Tags: three.js, rotation

I'm trying to rotate object around it's own axis, but nothing want to work. I tried all of functions from documentation, Euler's one, etc. But it just don't want to rotate at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate an object on its own (local) axis by using a pattern like this one:

```
var axis = new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z ).normalize(); // create once and reuse it

object.rotateOnAxis( axis, radians );
```

Make sure the axis has length 1.

Additional convenience methods are

```
object.rotateX( radians );
object.rotateY( radians );
object.rotateZ( radians );
```

If you want to rotate the object around a *world* axis, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385534/rotate-object-around-world-axis/19386917#19386917).

three.js r.85

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help you: 
You can rotate an object independently from the rest of the scene using this library https://github.com/albertopiras/threeJS-object-controls.

var controls = new THREE.ObjectControls(camera, renderer.domElement, yourMesh);

here a live demo https://albertopiras.github.io/threeJS-object-controls/