# threejs: How to perform rotation of object around it's local axes?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to rotate object on it's local axis using absolute rotation values. I am facing two issues
1. It looks like my object is rotating around world axes. For example set X, Y and Z to 45 degrees and try changing X.
2. If Y is set to 90 degrees, I get into gimbal lock issue.

I am using quaternion by setting rotation as follow

```
 cube.quaternion.setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(x, y , z));
```

A demo snippet is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2ycewjq/2/)

I came across this article [ThreeJS - rotation around object's own axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963615/threejs-rotation-around-objects-own-axis), but that didn't helped me.

I have been trying different solution using Euler and Matrix but still not able to make it work.

Looking for help to figure out the solution to this problem.