# Rotation on the Scene Axis, not the object

Tags: javascript, three.js

How might I rotate an object around the axis of the world instead of the object itself?
I've looked for an answer, but nothing has been working for me.

I made a hierarchy if swirls that I want to spin so that it looks sort of like waves. Unfortunately, even though I have checked and tested all my angles, it sways unlike it should, and I cannot get it to stay normal.

Here is a look at the functions I'm using:

```
function spinThePortal(portal, axis, speed, rotation) {
  if (axis === 0) {
    portal.rotation.y += speed;
  } else {
    portal.rotation.x += speed;
  }

  setTimeout(function () {spinThePortal(portal, axis, speed, rotation);}, 50);
}
function createPortals(firstDoubleCoor, secondDoubleCoor, number) {
  var direction = 1, notDirection = 0;
  if (firstDoubleCoor[0][0] === firstDoubleCoor[1][0]) {
    direction = 0; //vertical lines
    notDirection = 1;
  }
  var amount = difference(firstDoubleCoor[0][notDirection], firstDoubleCoor[1][notDirection]);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: portalColorList[number]});
  var block = new THREE.CubeGeometry(baseSize / 20, baseSize / 20, baseSize / 20);
  function squiggle(coor) {
    var root = new THREE.Mesh(block, material);
    root.position.set(coor[0][0] * baseSize, coor[0][1] * baseSize, baseSize);
    var parent = root;
    for (var i = 0; i < amount * 43; i++) {
      object = new THREE.Mesh(block, material);
      object.position.x = baseSize / 30;
      parent.add(object);
      parent = object;
    }
    scene.add(root);
    root.traverse(function(object) {
      object.rotation.set(Math.PI / 10, Math.PI / 10, 0);
    });
    if (direction === 1) root.rotation.set(0, 0, -Math.PI / 4);
    else root.rotation.set(0, 0, Math.PI / 4);
    if (spinPortals) spinThePortal(root, direction, portalSpinSpeed, 0);
  }
  squiggle(firstDoubleCoor);
  squiggle(secondDoubleCoor);
}
```

I don't know what the problem is, but here is a link if you need to see my full creation: [Click](http://gamingjs.com/ice/?g#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)

Comment: Please let me know if there is an easier way to fix this problem!

Comment: Duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385534/rotate-object-around-world-axis

Comment: Sort of, but none of the answers on that one worked for me.